# GNOME: Inhibit shutdown while backup is running

Tags: python, linux, debian, gnome

System: Debian 7 32bit

I'm trying to prevent the shutdown of my laptop during backups (obnam), and I think I can use `inhibit` to do so.

I found information on how to do this [here](http://www.lucidelectricdreams.com/2011/06/disabling-screensaverlock-screen-on.html), but when I execute this in the python shell

```
import dbus
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
proxy = bus.get_object('org.gnome.SessionManager','/org/gnome/SessionManager')
```

I get the error
`dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files`

list_names confirms that:

> > > bus.list_names()
> > >           dbus.Array([dbus.UTF8String('org.freedesktop.DBus'), dbus.UTF8String(':1.16'), dbus.UTF8String('org.gnome.Terminal.Display_0'), dbus.UTF8String(':1.14'), dbus.UTF8String(':1.15'), dbus.UTF8String('org.gnome.GConf'), dbus.UTF8String(':1.2')], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))

Q1: Why is `org.gnome.SessionManager` unavailable?
Q2: Are there other (GNOME-related) possibilities to prevent shutdown during execution of a backup?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use the dbus interface from a root shell, but the root user did not have a valid GNOME session (of course).

Running the same code as my own (logged-in) user gave the desired result.